# csv file formatting to display certain columns only

Tags: shell

Suppose i have a huge csv file having two fields.

```
name country
aa   n.k
kk   u.s
cc   u.k
dd   u.s
```

How can i select only those entries that are of u.s using shell scripting in linux?

Comment: use grep: `grep -E "u\.s$"`

Comment: The title says "certain *columns*" – I don't think you really mean that, do you?

Comment: may be you want `awk '$2=="u.s"` inpuf.csv`